# Don't wait for long running child process on server kicked off via PHP in browser

Tags: php, unix, child-process

I have before me a PHP function that wants to kick off a long-running child process. The user of the web-page doesn't need see the result of the long running process. Currently the code uses backticks to launch the child process:

```
<?php
  // stuff
  $res = `do_long_command_that_takes_10_minutes`;
?>
```

As you might imagine, the browser is held up by this until it sends a 4xx error when the limit in the conversation is reached. In C, I'd fork/exec and set various flags. So my idea was to do something like this :

```
<?php
    $pid = pcntl_fork(); // fork
    if ($pid < 0)
        exit;
    else if ($pid) // parent
        exit;
    else { // child
   
        $sid = posix_setsid();
    
        if ($sid < 0)
            exit;

        `do_long_command_that_takes_10_minutes`;
 
    }   
?>
```

Then I thought there could be a php time limit per se that gets exceeded on the server:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Other than setting PHP's `set_time_limit()` to a large amount of time, is there a better alternative?

Comment: queue the job somewhere and have a separate application runs it at set interval.

Comment: To elaborate on @BagusTesa solution, there are higher level queue concepts, complicated to simple MySQL, but generically you submit a job which returns automatically and the client then gets a ticket to check in on. Server-side, you have a daemon/cron that checks the job queue and optionally reports on progress, if possible, but otherwise reports when the job is done.

Comment: …ranging from complicated to just simple MySQL…